# Backend filter not working

Tags: magento-2.1, grid

**See picture**
[image]

No css and or no filter are available. We have installed Magento 2.0 with all filter working (Grid) and after upgrade to 2.1.8, the filter or grid have disapear, not only for the product but all page that have this type of filter.

I have search and found Nothing about it. Does someone have seem this problem before?

We use plesk, PHP 7.0.22 & Mariadb 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the problem.

**Here is the solution:**

Just add this line in the root .htaccess file of the magento at the end

```
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
    ModPagespeed off
</IfModule>
```

It works now
[image]